# Apple LLVM 6.0 preprocessor magical #if defined()

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working on a project which has a lot of dependencies. It is written in Objective-C with C++ libraries. It uses cross platform code with conditional compilation for different platforms in the libraries.

After the latest update I have encountered a peculiar issue with preprocessor macros with this

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#warning WARNING_1
#elif defined(DEBUG_gibberish)
#warning WARNING_2
#elif defined(SOMETHING)
#warning WARNING_3
#else
#warning WARNING_DEFAULT
#endif
```

code.

In this case `DEBUG` macro is defined in Xcode Apple LLVM 6.0 Preprocessing section

Please see the pic [image: screenshot]

So basically the problem is that #if defined() doesn't work as expected for this particular project. If I copy the same code to some clean test project it works as expected.

It also has another interesting effect, if I define `DEBUG_gibberish` then it will be evaluated instead of else case. After performing a couple of experiments it seems that it always evaluates/uses the first true condition and then the second true condition or `#else` if there was no second true condition.

I have already tried to clean project, clean derived data, restart Xcode, reboot my mac and even voodoo dolls.

I would appreciate any thought on why this happens and how to fix it.

EDIT1: I have a hierarchy of Xcode projects in my main project. The problematic library is a subproject in my main project. If I try to build it separately it works fine. If I compile it as dependency from main project I encounter this issue.

Comment: Learn how to get the preprocessed form of some file. Try `clang -C -E somefile.cc > somefile.ii` (or `g++ -C -E somefile.cc > somefile.ii`). Read wikipage on [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem.

I use some of the headers from third party libraries in my project to make my own subclasses of libraries' classes.

1. I believe Xcode gives a composite representation of warnings:

   In my code it shows `WARNING_1` after preprocessing of the header in
   library where `DEBUG` macro is defined.

   Then it shows `WARNING_DEFAULT` after preprocessing the same header
   in my project where `DEBUG` macro is not defined.

   But both warnings are shown as if they are in the same file.
2. By doing that it led me to conclusion that something is wrong with preprocessor or my code. Because of that I didn't think about simple thing that my project and library are built separately and my project doesn't contain needed macros.

So in the end solution was simple, I had to define needed macros in my project and then it compiled fine.